# Directory Ownership in Container: root vs mambauser

Tags: docker, permissions, root, mamba, micromamba

We're attempting to move one of our images from using miniconda3 as the base image to micromamba (1.5-bookworm-slim).

Our repository contains a Makefile that has commands to build the image and run a few tests.

The build is nothing special, and so is the Dockerfile. (We briefly switch to `root` to install a package using APT. The default user within the micromamba image is `mambauser`.)

The test command is as follows:

```
docker run --mount type=bind,source="$$(pwd)/test-data",target=/assets --mount type=bind,source="$$(pwd)/test-output",target="/tmp/test-output"  image_name:tag [call to script and arguments omitted]
```

This eventually fails on my Ubuntu system because the script is not able to write to the /tmp/test-output directory because it is owned by `root`. However when a colleague runs it on his Mac, the owner of the folder is `mambauser` and the test runs successfully.

When I explicitly add `--user mambauser` to the `run` command, the owner shows up as `1000`, but the test still fails.

Short of setting the user to `root` in the Dockerfile or running the test as `root`, is there a way to get this to work?

Happy to share relevant details of Dockerfile, system settings etc., if required.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Passing the user and group ID (or name) of the current user as an argument to the `docker run` command resolved the issue.

`docker run -u "$(id -u):$(id -g)"`

Refer: https://github.com/mamba-org/micromamba-docker/discussions/382#discussioncomment-7495825